# Mark and recapture with known upper bound

Tags: sampling, proportion, capture-mark-recapture

I was thinking this may be similar to a Mark and recapture problem where there is a known upper bound, hence the title.

I am doing a proportion but sometimes the estimate is larger than the known upper bound. Is there a way to restrict the possible answers to be between the two bounds?

Example: Assume out of a known population (U=10,000) a total of (X=8,505) people made (T=25,916) purchases. Of those, only (A=4,697) of them recorded anything with (R=8,632) recorded purchases.

The only unknown value is X and we wish to estimate it.

Most of the time the ratio estimate works great but does usually over-estimate the true size - and in some cases it is greater than the known population. In this case (X_est/T)=(A/R) which yielded X_est=14,102 which is larger than the known population.

Is there a way to incorporate the known population size to limit the estimate between 0 and U? Currently I am just censoring anything above U as U which seems ad hoc as the bounds should be 'built in' to the formula (hopefully).

Comment: Good question. But my initial reaction is that (because you have pretty large amounts of data) you have really uncovered evidence that those who record purchases either make different numbers of purchases on average than those who do not, or else do not record all their purchases.  This would call into question almost any inferences you might like to draw about all purchasers, so perhaps a better action to take is to note that fact (and act accordingly) rather than attempt to modify your estimator.